# how to avoid Ag grid with react memory leak?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, ag-grid

I 've the code in this plinker : https://plnkr.co/edit/MiRhkcG9sZTZO74P?preview

clicking on the toggle button should destroy the grid and unmount the component ( which i assume should release the memory resources ) , however inspecting the memory tab and getting a heap snapshot , I still see `gridAPI` and `rowNodes` are still there after the grid is destroyed . , is there any trick i have to do to solve this ?
screenshot from the heap snapshot is here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,
try to implement `getRowId` method
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-ids/#application-assigned-ids

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33841699)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the advice of the other answer posted by Ofry, and it worked!

I'm using TypeScript but the same principle should be applicable to JavaScript without particular issues.

Before, when AG Grid was calling my `valueSetter` defined in a `colDef` I had errors like this in console:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

In the main block of my React functional component code, I added the following method definition:

```
const MyEditor: React.FC<IMyEditorProps> = (props: IMyEditorProps) => {
    const getRowid = useMemo<GetRowIdFunc>(() => {
        return (params: GetRowIdParams) => params.data.id;
    }, []);
    ...
}
```

Here, `params.data` is the data object of your row. In my case, this object class has an `id` field which is always set and unique so it is appropriate to use as row id. Adapt this field choice to your own case.

Then use the new method as follows:

```
<AgGridReact
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    ...
    getRowId={getRowid}
    ...
    rowData={rowData}
/>
```

The error should now be gone and the value setter works as expected.